# Extract specific text lines from R output

Tags: r, text

I'm trying to extract specific information from a result that I get from a R function package. I'm  only familiar with Python so learning R language gives me some confusion.

Assuming this is the output of appnn (after printing it), a package that predicts protein aggregation

```
Prediction: 
$sequence
[1] "IFYFYGTTY"

$overall
[1] 1.076839

$aminoacids
          [,1]
 [1,] 1.076839
 [2,] 1.076839
 [3,] 1.076839
 [4,] 1.076839
 [5,] 1.076839
 [6,] 1.076839
 [7,] 1.028888
 [8,] 1.011057
 [9,] 1.011057

$hotspots
$hotspots[[1]]
[1] 1 9
```

Now all I need is just read the last 2 numbers (1 and 9), and from that I will have to extract a portion of the given string determined by these number (in this case it is the whole string since its length spans from spot 1 to 9).

In python it's rather simple but I have no idea how to do it with R.
Many thanks.

Comment: `substr(Prediction$sequence, Prediction$hotspots[[1]][1], Prediction$hotspots[[1]][2])`

Comment: Is `appnn` an R object that you've created from somewhere or is `Prediction` an R object? Where did that come from?

Comment: Its possible there's an extractor function for whatever your object is, so it might be as simple as `hotspots(appnn)` if that's your object. Read the documentation of the function that created it (`help(functionname)`)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a **reproducible example**. I'm guessing you are using the `appnn` package and creating an object called `predictions` like in this example:

```
library(appnn)
sequences <- c('STVIIE','KKSSTT','KYSTVI')
predictions <- appnn(sequences)
```

Now what does the documentation say about the return value:

```
 Value

 A list containing the amyloidogenicity propensity predictions for the
 polypeptides queried.

   overall
     The overall amyloidogenicity propensity prediction value for the sequence

   aminoacids
     The amyloidogenicity propensity prediction value per amino acid 

   hotspots
     A list of the amyloidogenic hotspots predicted in the sequence, limited by the first and last amino acid
```

So here I've queried three sequences, so I get back an R list with three elements. I can get the result for each one by selecting elements of the result, here the first:

```
> predictions[[1]]
$sequence
[1] "STVIIE"

$overall
[1] 0.9497568

$aminoacids
          [,1]
[1,] 0.9497568
[2,] 0.9497568
[3,] 0.9497568
[4,] 0.9497568
[5,] 0.9497568
[6,] 0.9497568

$hotspots
$hotspots[[1]]
[1] 1 6
```

This is another list with named components. The hotspots component is itself a list with just one component, (perhaps because the result could be more than one hotspot for a sequence) so I can get it thus:

```
> predictions[[1]]$hotspots[[1]]
[1] 1 6
```

That returns an R vector (vectors and lists are slightly different things in R) of length 2, with values 1 and 6.

Comment: Wonderful! I tried both of your and joel.wilson's and it worked like a charm. However, there is another problem if a sequence doesn't return $hotspots[[1]]. Take 'KKSSTT' as an instanace, the $hotspots[[1]] just returns as a 'list()' which is unable to extract. Is there a way to deal with it as I'm planning on iterate a lot of sequence automatically.

Comment: That's an empty list, so you could first test if the length of the `$hotspots` is greater than 0.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'm working on writing a function to write the given string to the text file after calculated it.

Comment: Okay but its *not* a string, its a length-2 vector, like a list in python: `[1, 6]` (but indexed from 1 in R unlike 0 in python).

Comment: Thanks again mate. I'm done with the if statement where it writes values of the vector to a text file and now I'm working writing the function. Should not be a big problem I hope. Now I'm trying to read a text file which stores multiple strings. It looks like this: Line#1: string Line#2: string... Huge pile of strings that I don't dare to count :P Should I read the text file, assign all of these string to a list, then iterate through all of them? Or I just read each line directly from the text file and then do the calculation, return the vector and then write the output?